# Need to include the working code with multiple cyclic mode is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I need to run all templates on the mode based, So I'm having `firstmode` which is needs to run the corresponding template based `mode`

Input I'm having:

```
<section>
<p class="p heading">Heading</p>
<p class="normal">Text</p>
</section>
```

Working XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        
        <xsl:variable name="firstmode">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="firstmode"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:variable>
    
        <xsl:sequence select="$firstmode"/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="firstmode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="firstmode"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
  <xsl:param name="class-map">
   <name>
      <old>heading</old>
      <new>Headings</new>
   </name>
   <name>
      <old>normal</old>
      <new>Actual</new>
   </name>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="class-map" match="name/new" use="../old"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/@class[key('class-map', tokenize(.), $class-map)]" mode="firstmode">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="key('class-map', tokenize(.) , $class-map)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p" mode="firstmode">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <normal>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </normal>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

```
<p style="Headings"><normal>Heading</normal></p>
<p style="Actual"><normal>Text</normal></p>
```

Once included the `mode="firstmode"` in the templates, the expected outputs are not getting. Please provide me the suggestion for how to handling this.

Comment: Please try to reduce code snippets to a minimum to demonstrate the actual problem. It is not clear what you need all the modes for or which output you want and which error or wrong output you get. In general, to keep processing in a mode, you use `<xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>` (of course often with a particular `select` but that is not the point here). so I guess where you want to apply-templates and have changed from no `mode` attribute on the `xsl:template` to `mode="firstmode"`, you want to add `mode="#current"` inside on any `apply-templates`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have edited the question, please see now

Comment: You have reduced the code sample but you have not told us which wrong result you get and what you want to achieve. Also I made a suggestion on adding `mode="#current"` on any `apply-templates` you use inside a template tied to a mode. And the original suggestion you seem to continue to complicate had `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, now that you use a named mode it might help to declare `<xsl:mode name="firstmode" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`. But it is hard to tell what you need exactly.